# How to configure Nginx for page refresh/reload

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have deployed two ear files on backend server. One with web context-root '/' and other with '/bli'. I am using Nginx to pass request to backend server. 
Let's say xyz is external url which is passing request to backend server via nginx.

This is what is happening- 
1) https://xyz - works fine. Page refresh/reload also works fine
2) https://xyz/bli - redirects to myserver.com/bli/ and gets an error
3) https://xyz/bli/ - works fine but page refresh/reload redirects to myserver.com/bli/

myserver.com in non-resolvable URL so I get an error

I tried including below directive -

```
location /bli/{
      proxy_pass https://backend;
      proxy_set_header Host myserver.com;
}
```

This solved problem of redirection to myserver.com. But it instead redirects to https://xyz:8011/bli/ which gives an error. It will work with https://xyz:443/bli/. Don't know from where port 8011 comes in URL.

I also tried this but it redirects to index file on nginx-

```
location /{
try_files $uri $uri/index.html
}
```

I tried this but didn't work-

```
location /{
try_files $uri $uri/bli /bli
}
```

Here is my conf file

```
server { 
listen *:8011;
root /apps/nginx/con/htdocs;
status_zone application_8011;

error_page 404 /error404.html;
error_page 500 502 503 504 /error500.html;

location /error404.html {
root /apps/nginx/con/htdocs/error_b;
}
location /error500.html {
root /apps/nginx/con/htdocs/error_b;
}
location / {

proxy_pass https://backend;
proxy_set_header Host myserver.com;

}
location /index.html {
root /apps/nginx/con/htdocs;
}

}
```

Refreshing https://xyz:/bli/ removes / at end and redirects to myserver.com/bli/ . Is there a way I can avoid removing / while refresh so that it refreshes https://xyz:/bli/. Or what do I need to include in my config file to resolve page refresh issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following solution worked for me -

```
location /{
      proxy_pass https://backend;
      proxy_set_header Host myserver.com;
      port_in_redirect off
}

location /bli/{
          proxy_pass https://backend/bli/;
          proxy_set_header Host myserver.com;
          port_in_redirect off
}
```